# Makefile relative working directory

Tags: c++, c, makefile, git-submodules, autotools

I have the following structure of a project:

```
/ProjectRoot
.../origin/                    (Git submodule with a remote open source project)
.../origin/Makefile           (original makefile for Autotools)
Makefile                      (adjusted makefile fir MinGW and local dependencies)
```

I am adding some files to the project in the root directory and modifying the Makefile, but want to keep the origin folder the same as the remote repository.

Is it possible to set a working directory in the root Makefile so that all files referenced inside it are taken from the origin folder? I am aware of the **-C /origin/** command of the `make` executable, but this command runs '/origin/Makefile' and not the root Makefile.

I tried to manually add /origin/ prefix to files, but it doesn't work because many targets are named after file names and I get total mess. Now I just copy the content of the root Makefile to the origin Makefile and hard reset origin changes whenever I update the submodule from remote. Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: Instead of copying the files, you can create a `softlink` from within `origin` to the `root`  and try

Comment: [`vpath`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search) might be of use here but unless you have your own source/etc. files in `/ProjectRoot` directly I would probably just suggest `mv Makefile origin/Makefile.mingw` and then just use `make -f Makefile.mingw` and be done with it.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh, thanks! This `-f` I was missing - much better than copying content from one to another.  I am very new to the C world and tooling :facepalm: